# How do I get a div to occupy 90% of the width of any size of monitor?

Tags: css

What is the css for a div which occupies 90% of the screen in any size of monitor?

Comment: @klez: Things like please, greetings, and similar things are a little bit discouraged by the SO community, actually.  I've seen people edit that stuff out.  Though using a command as the OP did is discouraged, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Er...

```
div { width: 90%; }
```

or

```
div { margin: 0 5%; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.myClass{
  width: 90%;
}

<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div { position:absolute; left:5%; right:5% }
```

Test and see...

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .myClass{
        width: 90%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="myClass"></div>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Or,

```
<div style="width: 90%;"></div>
```

But dude, seriously, check out the [W3C's CSS2 reference manual](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference.asp) and at least *try* to find the answer by yourself.

Comment: how make it center allignment